Rig out of place in Object and Pose Mode
I've been working on a model for some time now (this is my first model that actually didn't crash :D).
When I go into Edit Mode it's completely normal, but when I go to Pose or Object Mode, the rig is out of place.
The first screenshot below is in Edit Mode, and the second is what happens in the two other modes :/
How do I fix this?









Edit Mode
Object/Pose Mode




Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Apart from seeing your Blend file as @moonboots says, it would help if both of your images were shown in direct Front view (1 on the Numpad). Did you apply the Scale to both the armature and the model in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale) before parenting?

I managed to fix the issue, turns out i didn't scale the rig to the same size as the metarig (for some reason it spawns in smaller)
